# SplitContainer's panel as the MDI parent for other forms

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent, splitcontainer

I have got a control with a `Splitcontainer` added. I want to place 
another forms on the second panel (`Panel2`). However, it is not possible to
set the `MDIParent` property of a brand new form to `Panel2`.

Thus, the question is - how can I set the `SplitContainer's` panel as the `MDIParent` for another controls?

Thank you in advance for the clues!

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An MDIParent can only be another Form. What you need to do is set `TopLevel` to False on the child Form. Then you can add it to any control just like it was any other control (by adding it to the parent control's `Controls` collection). However, it won't work like it does in an MDI container (as in you won't be able to minimize or maximize it).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make Panel-Splitter-MdiClient Form see [panel and MDI in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571843/panel-and-mdi-in-c/4571863#4571863)

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to use the splitcontainer to load different subforms this may help. Instead of using WinForms, you could use classes derived from panels containing all the widgets that a normal WinForm would have. To display them, simply add them to your splitcontainer's Panel2 controls collection.

Some events and methods to keep in mind are:

- subformPanel.ParentChanged (do some initialization and subscribe to any parent events)
- subformPanel.ParentChanged (do some cleaning up and unsubscribe to parent events)
- Parent.Controls.Remove (destroy the subformPanel)

Comment: Can you show example of Classes derived from panels