# panel and MDI in c#

Tags: c#

following this link
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MDITabBrowsing.aspx
I made MDI and things are working well.
But I  want to use mainform a panel which is splitted. In splitted panel 2. I can see my form numbers in tabbar but cann't see my form. It appears under panel. how can i see it above/ on panel.
reagrds,

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a `SplitContainerControl`, use a `Splitter` control.

Answer (score 8):

First off, if you're going to ask questions on SO, you need to mark an answer for each one as correct.  You've currently asked 11 questions and haven't marked any of them as having a correct answer.  Users who take the time to answer your questions earn reputation only when their answer is marked as the correct one.  So please take a moment to do this.  You may find your questions falling on deaf ears if you continue to ask without feedback.

To mark an answer as correct, pick the one that best helped you, and on the left, under the number of votes the answer received, there is a check-mark.  Click on this, and the check-mark will turn green, marking the answer as the accepted one.

As for you question:  If I understand what you're trying to do, what you want to use is a regular panel.  Drop it onto your MDI window surface, and set it to dock left.  Make it as wide as you want.  Now, when you show a child window, it will fill/occupy the space in the right hand side of the MDI window, and will not appear under the panel on the left.

If you want, you can make the panel on the left resizeable as follows:

1. Drop a panel onto the MDI form
2. Set it to dock left and size it appropriately
3. Drop a splitter control into the right side of the MDI window (the dark grey background, not on the panel)
4. The splitter will appear to the right of the panel, and your MDI windows will dock to the right and be resizeable

HTH,
James

Comment: PS:  What Hans said : )  Sorry, opened this question a while ago to answer and got sidetracked, before you'd submitted yours.  Leaving mine up for the additional info, but gave you a +1.

Answer (score 2):

MDI forms are a parented to the MDI child window.  The dark gray background of the MDI parent.  If you put a panel on the parent, you'll overlap that child window.  And thus overlap the forms as well.

The only fix for this is to set the Dock property of the panel.  Say to the left.  That makes the MDI child window resize itself to occupy the remaining space of the parent form.  The panel now no longer overlap the MDI forms and they in turn won't overlap the panel.